# Multiple Filters on a SDK Request

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

on https://code.exacttarget.com/sdks/fuel-sdk-interacting-list-subscriber it shows how to filter by a SubscriberKey, but how would I filter by ListID **and** Status?

Comment: Would you mind marking this question as answered? Thanks!

Comment: how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP from this [file on the SDK repo](https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-PHP/blob/Dot9/objsamples/sample-folder.php#L38)

```
$myObj->filter = array('LeftOperand' => array('Property' => 'ListID','SimpleOperator' => 'equals','Value' => '12345'), 'LogicalOperator' => 'AND', 'RightOperand' => array('Status' => 'ContentType','SimpleOperator' => 'equals','Value' => 'ACTIVE'));
```

Comment: The right operand was causing an error but the concept was clear and I was able to update properly.

Comment: this sdk is much easier to use what i had built previously on my own, but i'm just starting out with it and Email API is very small part of what I do on daily basis. thanks for the quick response!

Comment: It will save time, and will get better as it's built out. Glad you are using it.

Comment: BTW - make sure you mark questions as answered if you find them helpful - just check the mark to the left.